# Django FormPreview - What is it for?

Tags: python, django, forms

While looking across the Django documentation, I came across the [FormPreview](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/).

The description says this:

> Django comes with an optional “form preview” application that helps automate the following workflow:
>
> “Display an HTML form, force a preview, then do something with the submission.”

What is meant by "force a preview"?  What would you use this feature for an in application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force a preview means the users are forced to see the value they have inserted on the form input fields, before django actually saves it to the database.

One example is [django comment system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/), which enforce the users to take a look at the comment they have written before django actually saves it to the database. You would see that the users are redirected to another page to take a look at their comment, and after that there is a submit button to actually save the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think they mean (I use django but I didn't know of this until now..) that you can let people write, for example in a textarea box like I'm doing right now. After the user submits it the system would preview it to the user and give him the chance to read and edit what he submitted, before it being submitted again all the way to the database.